# Method to get when UIWebView starts displaying content before `webViewDidFinishLoading`is called

Tags: ios, uiwebview

UIWebViewDelegate has one method `webViewDidFinishLoading`that is called when the page requested finished to load. The browser starts displaying data as soon as it has something to display before this method is called and everything has been loaded.

I show a  view  while the page is being loaded and the browser shows a blank page, but I can't  use `webViewDidFinishLoading`method to dismiss it. If I do so, the view will keep visible after the first content is displayed but before `webViewDidFinishLoading`is called.

Is there a method I can call to get when UIWebView starts displaying content on screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

On your UIWebViewDelegate and hide the view on the 3rd request loaded or something like that...